# Angular Reactive Forms data rendering only in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: angular, forms, rxjs, cross-browser, angular-reactive-forms

While fetching the data from the server into Angular reactive forms, everything works properly in Mozilla Firefox, but not in other browsers. Server endpoint is tested via Postman tool and it works fine. Below are the relevant code chunks that display the form definitions and their functionality.

This device selection displays Solar generators and by clicking on one, we call a getDevice() function that expects an id from a selected Solar Generator

```
<form [formGroup]="createSolarGeneratorForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="select_device">Select device</label><br />
    <select name="deviceName" (change)="changeDeviceName($event)" formControlName="deviceName" class="custom-select"
      id="deviceName" required>
      <option name="deviceName" [value]="solar.deviceName" *ngFor="let solar of solars; index as i"
        (click)="getDevice(solar?.id)"> {{ solar.deviceName }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

`getDevice()` - a method that's supposed to patch values from the selected Solar to the current form

```
getDevice(id: number) {
  this.solarService.getSolarGeneratorById(id).subscribe(response => {
    this.selectedSolar
      = response;
    this.islandService.getIslandByName(this.selectedSolar?.island.islandName).subscribe(response => {
      this.island
        =
        response[0];
      this.createSolarGenerator Form.patchValue({
        currentPower: this.selectedSolar?.currentPower,
        temperatureIrradiance: this.selectedSolar?.temperatureIrradiance,
        island: this.island
      });
    })
  });
}
```

These are the fields that should get patched

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Current power</label><br />
  <select name="currentPower" (change)="changeCurrentPower($event)" formControlName="currentPower" class="custom-select"
    id="currentPower">
    <option [selected]="true">{{ selectedSolar?.currentPower }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Temperature irradiance</label><br />
  <select name="temperatureIrradiance" (change)="changeTemperatureIrradiance($event)"
    formControlName="temperatureIrradiance" class="custom-select" id="temperatureIrradiance">
    <option [selected]="true">{{ selectedSolar?.temperatureIrradiance }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="islandid">This device belongs to island</label><br />
  <select name="islandname" (change)="changeIslandId($event)" formControlName="island_name" class="custom-select"
    id="islandname">
    <option [selected]="true">{{ (selectedSolar)?.island.islandName}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This is the form's structure

```
createSolarGeneratorForm = this.fb.group({
  deviceName: ['', [Validators.required]],
  maxPower: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]],
  currentPower: [''],
  temperatureIrradiance: [''],
  island: [''],
});
```

API call from the service returning SolarGenerator by passing an id

```
getSolarGeneratorById(id: number) {
  let params = new HttpParams().set("id", id);
  return this.httpclient.get<SolarGenerator>(`~${API_URL}/api/solarGenerator/find_by_id`, {params});
}
```

The API call works properly when called via Postman tool
[image: 6]

I've tried testing in Chrome and Brave and nothing happens when a getDevice() function gets called by a user click.

Comment: You passing `id` as an optional parameter but as per your `getDevice()` function its necessary.

Comment: Please add code instead of pictures! So the people can use it.